# How do I convert a numpy uint8 to the default int type in Python?

Tags: python

How to I convert a `uint8` created by numpy to a standard Python `int` so that it can be serialized to json?

Comment: Just do `int(num)`

Comment: I know this question is dead simple, but I was frustrated by inability to google for it. I would've expected a `uint` to get coerced to `int`, but I don't have enough of an understanding of python to know why this step is required for json serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider `int`.

```
a = numpy.uint8(some_number)
b = int(a)
print(type(b)) # <class 'int'>
```